# Adding a bottom border to an Entry in Xamarin Forms iOS with an image at the end

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Now before anyone ignores this as a duplicate please read till the end. What I want to achieve is this

[image: What I want to achieve]

I've been doing some googling and looking at objective c and swift responses on stackoverflow as well. And this response [StackOverFlowPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619851/get-controls-dimensions-in-customrenderer-xamarin-forms-ios/36621303) seemed to point me in the right direction.  The author even told me to use ClipsToBounds to clip the subview and ensure it's within the parents bounds. Now here's my problem, if I want to show an image on the right side of the entry(Gender field), I can't because I'm clipping the subview.

For clipping, I'm setting the property IsClippedToBounds="True" in the parent stacklayout for all textboxes.

This is the code I'm using to add the bottom border

```
     Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
           var myBox = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 40, 1000, 1))
           {
               BackgroundColor = view.BorderColor.ToUIColor(),
           };
           Control.AddSubview(myBox);
```

This is the code I'm using to add an image at the beginning or end of an entry

```
private void SetImage(ExtendedEntry view)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.ImageWithin))
    {
        UIImageView icon = new UIImageView
        {
            Image = UIImage.FromFile(view.ImageWithin),
            Frame = new CGRect(0, -12, view.ImageWidth, view.ImageHeight),
            ClipsToBounds = true
        };
        switch (view.ImagePos)
        {
            case ImagePosition.Left:                           
                Control.LeftView.AddSubview(icon);
                Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                break;
            case ImagePosition.Right:
                Control.RightView.AddSubview(icon);
                Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

After analysing and debugging, I figured out that when OnElementChanged function of the Custom Renderer is called, the control is still not drawn so it doesn't have a size. So I subclassed UITextField like this

```
 public class ExtendedUITextField : UITextField
    {
        public UIColor BorderColor;
        public bool HasBottomBorder;
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            if (HasBottomBorder)
            {
                BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                var myBox = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 40, Frame.Size.Width, 1))
                {
                    BackgroundColor = BorderColor
                };
                AddSubview(myBox);
            }


        }

        public void InitInhertedProperties(UITextField baseClassInstance)
        {
            TextColor = baseClassInstance.TextColor;
        }

    }
```

And passed the hasbottomborder and bordercolor parameters like this

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = e.NewElement as ExtendedEntry;


            if (view != null && Control != null)
            {
                if (view.HasBottomBorder)
                {
                    var native = new ExtendedUITextField
                    {
                        BorderColor = view.BorderColor.ToUIColor(),
                        HasBottomBorder = view.HasBottomBorder
                    };
                    native.InitInhertedProperties(Control);
                    SetNativeControl(native);
                }
}
```

But after doing this, now no events fire :(
Can someone please point me in the right direction. I've already built this for Android, but iOS seems to be giving me a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figured out that when OnElementChanged function of the Custom Renderer is called, the control is still not drawn so it doesn't have a size.

In older versions of `Xamarin.Forms` and iOS 9, obtaining the control's size within `OnElementChanged` worked....

You do not need the `ExtendedUITextField`, to obtain the size of the control, override the `Frame` in your original renderer:

```
public override CGRect Frame
{
    get
    {
        return base.Frame;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Width > 0 && value.Height > 0)
        {
            // Use the frame size now to update any of your subview/layer sizes, etc... 
        }
        base.Frame = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I gotta start eating those Sushi's you eat :)